# Javascript call special function after confirm

Tags: javascript

I made confirm function which shows special div to confirm or not. The task is, when I confirm some action I need to call another function, which I need to write into onClick attribute in my button.

There is what I want:

```
<button onClick="jsShowConfirmDiv(); jsMyFunction()">
  <span>Edit</span>
</button>
```

This is one button, but another will be something like this:

```
<button onClick="jsShowConfirmDiv(); jsAnotherFunction()">
  <span>Detail</span>
</button>
```

I need to call my functions (jsMyFunction() and jsAnotherFunction() only when I click on button yes.

For better imagination there is function in actual version (working, but limitless by parameter, and I think, than that is bad solution):

```
function jsShowConfirmMessage(content, yesFunction, par1, par2, par3) {
  $("id_confirm_message").setAttribute("classType", "confirm");
  $("id_popup_confirm_content").innerHTML = content;

  $("id_confirm_message_overlay").className = "popup_visible";
  window.location.hash = "#id_confirm_message_overlay";

  $("id_confirm_yes").stopObserving('click');

  $("id_confirm_yes").observe('click', function() { 
    jsHideConfirmMessage();
    if (!par1) {
      yesFunction();
    } else if (!par2) {
      yesFunction(par1);
    } else if (!par3) {
      yesFunction(par1, par2);
    } else {
      yesFunction(par1, par2, par3);
    }

  });

}
```

And I call it like this:

```
<button onClick="jsShowConfirmMessage('Really?', jsSpecialFunction, 'param')">
     <span>Edit</span>
</button>
```

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If user click no (or cancel, ...) you can throw an exception. Exception stop executing commands and second (third, ....) function will not be called.

Comment: I want to create something without exceptions, is there any solution?

Comment: Yes, you can set the function what you want to call in success (OK pressed) as parameter (callback) and in success case call it.